# How to track context in bot framework using Node js

Tags: node.js, bots

I want to track the context for my session using Bot framework. I think I can do that in C# but is that possible using Node js?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a context stack for each user, pushing an item on top of the stack for each message sent by the bot and matching context in FIFO order for each message recieved.

[Bot-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bot-context) is a cool npm package which provides an easy way to maintain context. The related [blog post](https://medium.com/@ashishshubham/maintaining-context-in-chatbots-2016b6a5b7c6#.4b10epgv6).